# Linux recursive rename files only

Tags: linux, shell, recursion, rename

I am trying to recursively rename all files within a directory and subdirectories to lower-case but leaving the directory names unchanged.

All examples I have found rename both files and directories to lower-case eg:

```
find ./ -depth -exec rename -n 'y/[A-Z]/[a-z]/' {} ";"
```

and

```
find . -type f|while read f; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"; done
```

How can I keep directories unchanged but rename all files?

Comment: What's the problem with the second one? `-type f` lists regular files only. Directories don't get listed.

Comment: you can also add the `-type f` to the first `find` command which to me looks the simplest, clearest and more easy to remember way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get rename on directory names because `find` command return full path of file names, then rename command done the rename also base on directory name. So if you have a file in directory `DIR1/FILE`, it will be rename to `dir1/file` while you don't want to rename the directory.

Here is the command for renaming only files name:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's:([^/]*$):lc($1):e' {} +
```

In above command, `([^/]*$)` matches only the last part of the path that doesn't contain a `/` inside a pair of parentheses`(...)` which it makes the matched part as group of matches. Then translate matched part(`$1` is index of first matched group) to lowercase with `lc()` function.

At the you need to ride the `-n` option to renaming on actual files.

> `-exec ... {} +` is for commands that can take more than one file at a
>   time (eg `cat`, `stat`, `ls`). The files found by `find` are chained
>   together like an `xargs` command. This means less forking out and for
>   small operations, can mean a substantial speedup. [[answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/558819/283843) by [@Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli)]

Comment: This still renames the last directory in tree as it iterates though. But can be fixed if change to: find . -name "*.type" -exec rename 's:([^/]*$):lc($1):e' {} +

Comment: @DonSmythe Uh, correct I missed `-type f`. fixed that. thank you.